# how to make a flag in shell cli app

Tags: git, shell

I am currently rewriting an old git plugin I made (`git-build`) which has two commands which I want to turn into one command with a `--flag`

```
run() {
  require_clean_work_tree rebase "Please commit or stash them."
  source git-build.sh
  git add .
  git commit -m 'Build $VERSION'
  git tag $VERSION
}

run-deploy() {
  require_clean_work_tree rebase "Please commit or stash them."
  source git-build.sh
  git add .
  git commit -m 'Build $VERSION'
  git tag $VERSION
  git push -tags
}
```

I wish to have `run-deploy` turn into `run --deploy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there is some special magic involved with `git` plugins that's as simple as

```
run() {
  require_clean_work_tree rebase "Please commit or stash them."
  source git-build.sh
  git add .
  git commit -m 'Build $VERSION'
  [ "$1" = '--deploy' ] && git tag $VERSION
}
```